# How to develop SmartList In C# like MSDynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, webforms

How can i develop smartlist in C# .Is there any idea

*User Select Fields and make a graph After this he want to save the settings for future and this setting show as a smartlist whenever user click the graph formed .User dont want to enter the setting again and again

Comment: Which fields...which graph....is it winform or webform or WPF???..Please explain in detail what you are trying to acheive

Comment: ASP Chart ,Its a webform .I want to make smartlist user select field and generate graph after this he saved his all settings for future next time he just click on the smartlist ,Smartlist menue open then he select his saved setting and graph open.User easily create Smartlist according to date .